# Where to find or compare travel insurance for airline bankruptcy

Tags: air-travel, insurance

I'm looking to buy travel insurance, mainly for the purpose of if the airline goes bankrupt. For information purposes, I'm looking to buy a ticket with British Airways at the end of the year mostly because they currently have a flexible option meaning I could change my ticket in the future for no cost.

I'm just concerned that a large number of airlines file for bankruptcy between now and then and I don't know anything about the risk of British Airways.

I don't have a credit card, it could be an option if it's cheaper than travel insurance. Maybe my mom could use her credit card and I give her the money.

Since I will be staying with my mom I won't have any risk of accommodation being paid for and I already have health insurance abroad so I'm hoping that it could mean cheaper insurance since I only need for bankruptcy.

I'm a permanent resident of Germany.

Comment: Before you have someone else buy the ticket for you on their card, check the 'money back' in case of financial problems of the seller, as I have seen 'rules' which only allow money back for the owner of the card, not for others who travel on the same payment. And also a minimum amount before they start getting the money back for you.

Comment: Whether an insurance policy covers a specific risk depends on the policy's terms and conditions. I would not trust advertising or headers, but would read the policy's T&Cs. If the company or agent will not provide them for examination before you purchase, shop elsewhere.

Comment: @user1898829 What research have you done so far? Eg a quick internet search on ‘what insurance covers airline failure’ threw up Scheduled Airline Failure Cover offered by various insurers

Comment: I searched for airline insurance bankruptcy. I found many tips on what to do if your airline goes bankrupt and some American insurance that only allows you to enter an American state. I also looked on here for airline bankruptcy but was unable to find anything useful about where to purchase insurance. I will now try to search for Scheduled Airline Failure Cover

Answer (score 2):

The cover you are looking for is called Scheduled Airline or End Supplier Failure. This section of cover reimburses any money lost as a result of an airline going into administration or filing for bankruptcy. If you paid for your ticket by credit card, then you would be able to claim the money back that way, although I am fairly sure the card must be yours and not someone else's.

In respect of a specific company who will provide the cover, it depends on where you are travelling from and your destination.

Answer (score 0):

I found travel insurance to compare prices https://www.check24.de/
This also gives me the option to remove health insurance.